# Compiling c++ code for meep using g++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, meep

this is the first time I've used Stackoverflow to ask a question. I have been searching for solutions to compiling c++ code using g++ in ubuntu and have found lots of related content, but nothing that answers my question directly... My goal is to be able to create control files in c++ rather than scheme, but when i compile in the ubuntu terminal it cannot find the meep.hpp file. so far i have installed meep using apt-get and beleive i have all required libraries... any ways here is the code I am using as a test, and the commands I have tried:

```
#include <meep.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace meep;

double eps(const vec &p) {
  if (p.x() < 2 && p.y() < 3)
    return 12.0;
  return 1.0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  initialize mpi(argc, argv); // do this even for non-MPI Meep
  double resolution = 20; // pixels per distance
  grid_volume v = vol2d(5,10, resolution); // 5x10 2d cell
  structure s(v, eps, pml(1.0));
  fields f(&s);

  f.output_hdf5(Dielectric, v.surroundings());

  double freq = 0.3, fwidth = 0.1;
  gaussian_src_time src(freq, fwidth);
  f.add_point_source(Ey, src, vec(1.1, 2.3));
  while (f.time() < f.last_source_time()) {
    f.step();
  }

  f.output_hdf5(Hz, v.surroundings());

  return 0;
}
```

the Commands I use are:

```
g++ FirstTest.cpp
```

or as said in other threads:

```
g++ -o FirstTest FirstTest.cpp -lmeep
```

if anyone can point me in the right direction i would greatly appreciate it! I am still quite new to linux

As mentioned in a comment below i have recently installed libmeep-dev and now get the followning

```
/tmp/ccBM5Uuc.o: In function `main':
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `meep::initialize::initialize(int&, char**&)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `meep::vol2d(double, double, double)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `meep::identity()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `meep::pml(double)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `meep::structure::structure(meep::grid_volume const&, double (*)(meep::vec const&), meep::boundary_region const&, meep::symmetry const&, int, double, bool, double, int)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `meep::symmetry::~symmetry()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to `meep::fields::fields(meep::structure*, double, bool, double, bool)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x200): undefined reference to `meep::grid_volume::surroundings() const'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `meep::fields::output_hdf5(meep::component, meep::volume const&, meep::h5file*, bool, bool, char const*)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `meep::gaussian_src_time::gaussian_src_time(double, double, double)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x363): undefined reference to `meep::fields::add_point_source(meep::component, meep::src_time const&, meep::vec const&, std::complex<double>)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `meep::fields::step()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x3a9): undefined reference to `meep::fields::last_source_time()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `meep::grid_volume::surroundings() const'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x405): undefined reference to `meep::fields::output_hdf5(meep::component, meep::volume const&, meep::h5file*, bool, bool, char const*)'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x437): undefined reference to `meep::fields::~fields()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x446): undefined reference to `meep::structure::~structure()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x464): undefined reference to `meep::initialize::~initialize()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x491): undefined reference to `meep::structure::~structure()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x4a5): undefined reference to `meep::symmetry::~symmetry()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x4bc): undefined reference to `meep::structure::~structure()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x520): undefined reference to `meep::fields::~fields()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x534): undefined reference to `meep::structure::~structure()'
FirstTest.cpp:(.text+0x55c): undefined reference to `meep::initialize::~initialize()'
/tmp/ccBM5Uuc.o: In function `meep::gaussian_src_time::~gaussian_src_time()':
FirstTest.cpp:(.text._ZN4meep17gaussian_src_timeD2Ev[_ZN4meep17gaussian_src_timeD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for meep::gaussian_src_time'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the commands you show? What errors (if any) do you get when running them? Please edit your question to include that information (copy-paste the complete output from the build command).

Comment: Install libmeep-dev This should help

Comment: to Amadeus... i installed libmeep-dev and it seemed to get past my previous errors... however im getting different errors haha

Comment: here is what the terminal said:

Comment: The errors you show are probably from the *first* command, where you don't actually *link* with the library. When you add `-lmeep` at the end what happens then?

Comment: just added -l meep after and in my Tests folder where the FirstTest.cpp files is located i get an a.out file

Answer (score 0):

Try point the include directory.
Looks like this

```
g++ -o FirstTest FirstTest.cpp -lmeep -I/example/include/path -L/example/lib/path
```

Maybe it is `-I/usr/include -L/usr/lib`

This is what you looking for https://github.com/stevengj/meep/blob/master/doc/docs/C%2B%2B_Tutorial.md

Comment: `-I/usr/include -L/usr/lib` is almost always redundant with the defaults.

Comment: The meep/ folder might is inside of /usr/include

Comment: when i installed meep i used the apt-get command... so to be honest im not sure where the meep.hpp file is located, however i have a version of meep downloaded from github which has the meep.hpp file which i moved over to my ubuntu virtual machine and placed it in the same folder as where my FirstTest.cpp is located

Comment: meep.hpp depends either meep/vec.hpp and meep/mympi.hpp.

Comment: so how/ what do i do to have those... i just sudo copied meep.hpp to the usr/incude folder and that brought me to the next compile error which says it requires vec.hpp

Comment: download meep.zip from github, then unzip and go to master-meep/ folder 
run sh autogen.sh && make && ./configure;
Wait for done, then compile your source with g++ source.cpp -o app `\`pkg-config --libs --cflags meep`\`